# Uploading captions with Vimeo API

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

Can you help me? I'm trying upload using Vimeo API captions to my video with PHP.

Here is Vimeo-api doc: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/texttracks

Unfortunately, there are no threads about Vimeo captions upload with PHP and Vimeo doesn't offers any code example to newer users.

I'm working in this way:

```
include __DIR__ . '/Vimeo/autoload.php';

// The client id and client secret needed to use the vimeo API
$clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// when getting an auth token we need to provide the scope
// all possible scopes can be found here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#supported-scopes
$scope = "public";

// The id of the user
$userId = 99999999;

// initialize the vimeo library
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);

// request an auth token (needed for all requests to the Vimeo API)
$token = $lib->clientCredentials($scope);

// set the token
$lib->setToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

// request video data
$videos = $lib->request("/me/videos/9999999");

// pretty print output
echo '<pre>' . var_export($videos, true) . '</pre>';
```

For example, according the vimeo-api-doc, the output is something like this for captions:

```
...
'texttracks' => 
    array (
      'uri' => '/videos/9999999/texttracks',
      'options' => 
      array (
        0 => 'GET',
        1 => 'POST',
      ),
      'total' => 0,
    ),
...
...
```

So, now, I have no idea about my next step, even reading again vimeo dev. page to see my next step, but I'm lost.

Can you help me solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: The API docs show you step by step instruction how to upload text track, you clearly already finish step 1, now go to step 2. Which part of step 2 you don't understand?

Comment: I'm confunsing about "POST https://api.vimeo.com{texttracks_uri}". I do not know how to perform it.

Comment: I have the answer and its short and sweet.  First of all the documentation at  https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/texttracks is out of date and there is no replacement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the Vimeo's documentation at  https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/texttracks is out of date and they have not updated it yet and it does not work! I went through the Vimeo.php source code and found an undocumented method named uploadTexttrack, here is the internal documentation and function prototype:

```
 /**
 * Uploads a text track.
 *
 * @link https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/texttracks
 * @param string $texttracks_uri The text tracks uri that we are adding our text track to
 * @param string $file_path The path to your text track file
 * @param string $track_type The type of your text track
 * @param string $language The language of your text track
 * @return string The URI of the uploaded text track.
 * @throws VimeoRequestException
 * @throws VimeoUploadException
 */
public function uploadTexttrack($texttracks_uri, $file_path, $track_type, $language)
```

Here is my test code that appears to work great, note that the VTT or SRT file has a relative path to your script and the CC name is extracted from the $file_path as the basename(). The '453355865' is the video id. Thank you Vimeo for saving my A??!  I have 130 videos that need the 14 languages below for the special needs kids schooling from home during the Covid 19. I work for a School System where many parents can't help there children because they don't know English.

```
        <?php
    include '../vimeo/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Vimeo\Vimeo;
    use Vimeo\Exceptions;
    use Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoUploadException;
    $client_id = 'your client id';
    $client_secret = 'your client secret';
    $access_token = 'your access token';
    $lib = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret, $access_token);
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.English.vtt", "captions", "en-US");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Amharic.vtt", "captions", "am");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Arabic.vtt", "captions", "ar");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Chinese Simplified.vtt", "captions", "zh-CN");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.French.vtt", "captions", "fr");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.German.vtt", "captions", "de");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Hindi.vtt", "captions", "hi");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Japanese.vtt", "captions", "ja");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Korean.vtt", "captions", "ko");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Mongolian.vtt", "captions", "mn");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Portuguese.vtt", "captions", "pt");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Punjabi.vtt", "captions", "pa");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Russian.vtt", "captions", "ru");
    $videos = $lib->uploadTexttrack("/videos/453355865/texttracks", "vtt/Circles 1107 My Acquaintances.Spanish.vtt", "captions", "es");
    ?>
```